# Logic Behind a JQuery Betting Game

Tags: jquery, comparison

I'm trying to figure out how to make the bet check against the 10 dollars in the #your-money id and if it's greater than 10 to show error, and if it's less than 0 show error.

```
var mybet = $( "#bet" );
var yourmoney = $( "#your-money" );

$( "#place-bet" ).click(function()
{
    if ( mybet <= yourmoney ) {
        $("#betting-money").val($("#bet").val());
    }
    if  ( mybet == 0 && mybet > 0 ){
         $("body").alert("Try another bet");
    }
});
```

Comment: `mybet == 0 && mybet > 0` is can never be true. The value cannot be equal to `0` **and** larger than `0` at the same time. I guess you want an OR: `||`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var mybet = $( "#bet" );
var yourmoney = $( "#your-money" );

    $( "#place-bet" ).click(function()
        {
        if ( mybet <= yourmoney ) {
                $("#betting-money").val($("#bet").val());
            }
        if  ( mybet > 10 || mybet < 0 ){
             $("body").alert("Try another bet");
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#place-bet").click(function()
    var mybet = parseFloat($("#bet").val());
    var yourmoney = parseFloat($("#your-money").val());
    {
    if (mybet <= yourmoney) {
        $("#betting-money").val(mybet);
    }
    if  (mybet < 0 || mybet > 10){
        alert("Try another bet");
    }
});
```

Comment: You need to make sure you get "mybet" and "yourmoney" inside the click event, or they'll be wrong at the time the event is fired.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this.

```
var mybet = $( "#bet" );
var yourmoney = $( "#your-money" );

$( "#place-bet" ).click(function()
{
    if  (yourmoney.val() > 10 || yourmoney.val() < 0 ){
         $("body").alert("Try another bet");
    }
    else{
        $("#betting-money").val($("#bet").val());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the AND comparison operator (&&) and should be using the OR (||)

if  ( mybet == 0 && mybet > 0 )

if  ( mybet == 0 || mybet > 0 )

You also have several other errors which I've fixed below.

```
$( "#place-bet" ).click(function()
{
    var mybet = $("#bet").val();
    var yourmoney = $("#your-money").val();

    if ( mybet <= yourmoney )
    {
                $("#betting-money").val(mybet);
    }
    if  ( mybet < 0 || mybet > 10 )
    {
             alert("Try another bet");
    }
});
```